# Explain this while loop to me (basic java)?

Tags: java, while-loop

What is the value of z when the following code finishes executing?

```
int x;
int y;
int z;

x = 1;
z = 1;

while (x <= 5)
{
  z = z + x;
  x = x + 1;
}
```

I know the answer is 16 but I keep running into errors when trying to compute it. I feel like I'm messing up a step in the loop in the beginning. I know I can just plug this into a java client and get the answer but I'm really trying to understand the loop sequence so as to be able to do it by hand.

Comment: [Tutorial on `while` loops.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Comment: What errors are you running in to? Additionally, what about the loop / code is unclear?

Comment: I was just unsure as to how the loop was reaching the value of 16 for z as with each iteration I was just trying to add up but i was getting mixed up as far was what the subsequent z values would be. the below answers helped a lot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    x = 1;
    z = 1;
```

Okay, x is 1 and z is 1.

```
    while (x <= 5)
    {
      z = z + x;
      x = x + 1;
    }
```

x is less than or equal to 5, so we perform this operation. We set z to 1+1 or 2. We set x to 1+1, or 2.

```
x = 2
z = 2

    while (x <= 5)
    {
      z = z + x;
      x = x + 1;
    }
```

2 is <= 5, so we loop. z = 2+2, or 4. x = 2+1, or 3.

```
x = 3
z = 4

    while (x <= 5)
    {
      z = z + x;
      x = x + 1;
    }
```

x is less than or equal to 5. Now z=4+3=7, x=3+1 = 4.

```
x = 4
z = 7

    while (x <= 5)
    {
      z = z + x;
      x = x + 1;
    }
```

Again, 4<=5, so z=7+4=11, x=4+1=5

```
x = 5
z = 11

    while (x <= 5)
    {
      z = z + x;
      x = x + 1;
    }
```

5 is <= 5, so we loop. z=11+6=16, x=5+1=6

```
x = 6
z = 16

    while (x <= 5)
    {
      z = z + x;
      x = x + 1;
    }
```

Oops, x is not <=5, so we're done. z is now 16.

Once you understand how this loop works, it's obvious. We start out at 1. Then we add 1, 2, 3, 4, and finally 5 to it. 1+1+2+3+4+5=16.

Answer (score 5):

To really understand it, just think like the computer. Write out what the while-loop is going to do to each of the variables on each iteration. I've omitted `y` because it doesn't seem to be used for anything.

```
                x |  z | (x <= 5) | z + x | x + 1
               ===+====+==========+=======+======
Initial:        1 |  1 |          |       |     
               ===+====+==========+=======+======
Iteration 1:    1 |  1 | true     |     2 |     2
Iteration 2:    2 |  2 | true     |     4 |     3
Iteration 3:    3 |  4 | true     |     7 |     4
Iteration 4:    4 |  7 | true     |    11 |     5
Iteration 5:    5 | 11 | true     |    16 |     6
Iteration 6:    6 | 16 | false    |       |
               ===+====+==========+=======+======
Final values:   6 | 16 |          |       |
```

When `x` equals `6`, the test `x <= 5` evaluates to `false`, so we break out of the loop. And now, at the end, we can see that `z = 16`.

Answer (score 2):

```
x=1
z=1
while(x is less than or equals to 5) {
z is z + x;
x is x+1
}
```

meaning first loop will be

```
z = 1 + 1 = 2
x = 1 + 1 = 2
```

second:

```
z = 2 + 2 = 4
x = 2 + 1 = 3
```

and so on until x is 5

Answer (score 2):

When learning loops, making a chart can make it a bit easier to see what is going on (though it is a bit tedious)

```
z  | x | while (x <= 5) | z + x | x + 1 | new z | new x
=======================================================
1  | 1 | true           |   2   |   2   |   2   |  2        
_______________________________________________________
2  | 2 | true           |   4   |   3   |   4   |  3
_______________________________________________________
4  | 3 | true           |   7   |   4   |   7   |  4
_______________________________________________________
7  | 4 | true           |   11  |   5   |  11   |  5
_______________________________________________________
11 | 5 | true           |   16  |  6    |   16  |  6
_______________________________________________________
16 | 6 | false          |  NA   |  NA   |  NA   |  NA
^ final value
```

By writing a table you can see how the value changes over time. Once you reach false, you know that your final value for z is the output.

Also, you can start to understand how the for-loop works and notice patterns

Answer (score 1):

This while loop is looping while x is less or equals with 5 and in each iteration it increase values of variables z and x.

You can use debugger to view all values step by step, or you can modify your code and print all values from variable like this:

```
int x;
int y;
int z;
int iteration = 1;

x = 1;
z = 1;

while (x <= 5)
{
  z = z + x;
  x = x + 1;
  iteration++;
  System.out.println("Iteration: " + iteration + " Values: x=" + x + " y=" + y + " z=" + z);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for including the System.out.println statement!

Comment: You're welcome, it is quick change, but you will be more effective if you use debugger and see what is happening in each iteration. In this case you can view all statements, values, etc. I suggest you to try this.

Answer (score 1):

The `while` statement keeps running untill a condition is true, in your case the condition is `x<=5`, but let's go step by step.

When the code first reachs the `while` your condition is true because `x=1`, so the block inside is executed and `z = 1 + 1 = 2` and `x = 1 + 1 = 2`, then the iteration starts again, this time  `z = 2 + 2 = 4` and `x = 2 + 1 =3` and so on until `x > 5` that renders the condition false and the program exit the while loop. At that point z will be 16.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite it like this, to make it clearer:

```
x = 1;
z = 1;

while (x <= 5)
{
  z += x;
  x += 1;
}
```

Z is incremented by x at each loop, while x is incremented by 1.

In other words :

```
z = 1;

for (x = 1; x <= 5; x++)
{
  z += x;
}
```

I'm pretty confident is easier to trace by hand now, isn't?